# Synchronize Firebird with MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization, firebird

I have two databases, one is a **Firebird** database, other is a **MySQL** database.

Firebird database is the main one where the information changes. I have to synchronize those changes to the other MySQL database.

I have no control over the Firebird one - I can just SELECT from it. I cannot add triggers, events or similar. I have all the control on the MySQL database.

The synchronization has to be done through 'internet' as these two servers are not connected in any way and are on different locations.

Synchronization has to be done in **PHP** on the server that also hosts the MySQL database.

Currently I just go through every record (every 15 minutes), calculate the hash of the rows, compare two hashes and if they don't match, I update the whole row. It works but just seems very wrong and not optimized in any way.

Is there any other way to do this? I am missing something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made the same thing once and I don't think there is a generaly better solution.

You can only more or less optimize what you have so far. For example:

- If some of the tables have a column with the "latest update" information, you can select only those that were changed since the last sync.
- You can change the comparison mechanism - instead of comparing and updating whole rows, you can compare individual columns and on the MySQL side update only the changed ones. I believe that it would speed things up in case of MyISAM tables, but probably not if you use InnoDB.

Comment: Having the 'latest update' column would be perfect but unfortunately it's not there. Guess that comparition mechanism is the only thing I can do. Thanks for the answer.